# How to call a method from a class inside the same module

Tags: crystal-lang

How do I call redis from a struct or a class?

```
module A::Cool::Module
  redis = Redis.new(host: ENV["REDIS_DEV_HOST"], port: 18163)
  redis.auth(ENV["REDIS_DEV_AUTH"])

  struct CoolStruct
    def CoolFunciton
       redis # => undefined method 'redis' for A::Cool::Module:Module
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried the following without success

```
module A::Cool::Module
  @@redis = Redis.new(host: ENV["REDIS_DEV_HOST"], port: 18163)
  @@redis.auth(ENV["REDIS_DEV_AUTH"])

  struct CoolStruct
    def CoolFunciton
       @@redis # => can't infer the type of class variable '@@redis'
    end
  end
end
```

```
module A::Cool::Module
  module DB
     redis = Redis.new(host: ENV["REDIS_DEV_HOST"], port: 18163)
     redis.auth(ENV["REDIS_DEV_AUTH"])
  end


  struct CoolStruct
    include A::Cool::Module::DB
    def CoolFunciton
       redis # => undefined local variable or method 'redis'
    end
  end
end
```

```
module A::Cool::Module
  module DB
     redis = Redis.new(host: ENV["REDIS_DEV_HOST"], port: 18163)
     redis.auth(ENV["REDIS_DEV_AUTH"])
  end


  struct CoolStruct
    include A::Cool::Module::DB
    def CoolFunciton
       A::Cool::Module::DB.redis # => undefined method 'redis'
    end
  end
end
```

I really have no idea how to do it.
And I don't want to create a redis connection for each class where I need redis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case is significant in Crystal. A module can have constants, which will be accessible throughout the module's scope (note the uppercase):

```
module A::Cool::Module
  REDIS = ...
  ...
end
```

(Also, you should really use `snake_case`, not `TitleCase` for a method name; so `cool_function`, not `CoolFunction`.)

Comment: I'm actually always using snake_case for methods, it was just for stack overflow that I created this code ( to show only what I was trying to achieve ) I didn't check if it was following the coding style convention. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. I don't think Crystal would even let you get away with it.